# How do I loot life crystals?

Tags: terraria

I bumped into these life crystals, which used to be looted with a hammer, but now in 1.2, I cannot do that anymore.

[image: Red crackled heart]

How do I loot the crystals?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [the official patch notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nubZZSGBoUiuKFKzWT7raMrPI35MQtDWSsL-MbHFgqs/preview?sle=true):

> - The hammer is now used for creating slopes, halftiles, and breaking walls only
> - Pickaxes will now remove blocks, placeable objects, and items such as Life Crystals and chests