# Heart crystals won’t break using any pickaxe ,why and how do I fix it?

Tags: terraria-console

I tried my iron and my copper pickaxe but neither work for breaking heart crystals! What do I do?

Comment: Only hammers could break background objects until 1.2-ish.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're somehow playing on an older version. Specifically, older than [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132865/how-do-i-loot-life-crystals/132870). In that case, pickaxes won't work, use a hammer.